# Deleting from one table also deletes from other table

Tags: postgresql

Postgres on Linux

When I do the following command.

```
 DELETE FROM some_table;
```

It also deletes data from another table. How do I found out how?

Comment: You have a on delete cascade constraint on this table to the other that the registries are being deleted

Comment: When I do `\d some_table`, I don't see foreign key or delete on cascade.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a foreign key constraint that points to your table and is defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Alternatively, there may be a trigger on the table that deletes the rows.

In `psql`, use `\d some_table` to see all such foreign keys and triggers.